# How to set adaptive constraints the right way

Tags: ios, constraints

I'm building an app and I want it to work on every iPhone and iPad. 
How do I do to make adaptive constraints that change for each device?
I know you can do something to detect the screen size and adapt the constraints, how do I do that? Is there an easy and clear tutorial?

Comment: It’s called learning. Learn about autolayout. Then apply what you’ve learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all constraints are depended on your project.when you can start project you take the view and add the 4 constant 0,0,0,0.After this if you can add multiple item in the page,you take the particular view for the particular item.If you take the particular view it can be easy for the set constraints.Very most important thing that you complete the design of your page and after create design you can set the constraints.It's can be easy way to set the constraints.Another most important thing is you can create your project in the small device like iphone-SE and after set constraints and run in medium device like iphone-6,7,8 and in the last run your program in big device like iphone-X,XSmax.